# How to align three Widgets in row. (one in the right corner, one in the left and one in the center)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a row and put three widgets in there. One that will be in the most right corner of the row, one that will be in the most left corner and one that will be in the center, I have been trying solutions for a while and I still can't make it look like I wanted. Added picture of what I want below.

**This is what I want to create:**

[image]

**and this is my code (the relevant part of it):**

> this code represent **one row** (in the real code i multiply it and changing the relevant thing.)

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print(title);
      },
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(
            title, // Name
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: size.width * .0365,
              color: Colors.black,
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            subTitle, // Name
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: size.width * .0365,
              color: const Color(0x9C9C9C9C),
              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios, // the arrow icon in the left of the row
            size: size.width * .04,
            color: const Color(
              0xA6A6A6A6,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I tried to wrap those Widgets with the Align Widget and use the `alignment: Alignment.center`, but still didn't succeed.

**this is what I got:**

[image]

as you can see the Widgets in the middle aren't align like I wanted. if Someone know what I have been missing please let me know.

**UPDATE**

now my code working like I wanted but now the text are centered but they aren't centered with the whole page. Someone know how can I fix that?

**this is the whole code of the page:**

```
// imports...

class EditProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfile({Key? key, this.user}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  final user;
  State<EditProfile> createState() => _EditProfileState(user);
}

class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {
  late UserData user;
  late String username;
  late String phoneNumber;
  late String location;
  late String gender;

  _EditProfileState(this.user);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Map<String, dynamic> data = user.getUserData();
    username = data["username"];
    phoneNumber = data["phoneNumber"];
    //location = data["location"];
    location = "location";
    gender = data["gender"];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text("Edit profile"),
        leading: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text(
                "Cancel",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        trailing: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("save");
              },
              child: const Text(
                "save",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 139, 182, 1),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * .03),
              child: Center(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: Image.network(
                    "some image path",
                  ).image,
                  radius: size.width * .14,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * .01),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print("changing pofile pic");
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Change Profile Photo",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: size.width * .035,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 139, 182, 1),
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * .04),
              child: Container(
                height: size.height * .25,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    filedRow(size, "Name", username),
                    filedRow(size, "Phone", phoneNumber),
                    filedRow(size, "Location", location),
                    filedRow(size, "Genger", gender),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  GestureDetector filedRow(Size size, String title, String subTitle) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: size.width * .036,
                color: Colors.black,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Text(
              subTitle,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: size.width * .036,
                color: Color(0x9C9C9C9C),
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
            size: size.width * .03,
            color: Color(0xA6A6A6A6),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**and this is what I get**

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same output from your snippet that you are trying to archive. Can you recheck ?

Comment: I recheck my code. Please make sure that the length of the titles (first widget) are different from each other. try put the values that are in the picture. It can be confusing but if they are in the same length it only look like they are in the middle.

Comment: can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I double-checked everything and you were right, I didn't notice that my headers were the same length, but I fixed everything. See corrected code and screenshot:

```
  Widget mainWidget() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("App bar"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            CustomRow(title: 'Name', choosedSetting: 'Alexey'),
            CustomRow(title: 'Phone', choosedSetting: '+375 29 154-52-52'),
            CustomRow(title: 'Gender', choosedSetting: 'Man'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String choosedSetting;

  const CustomRow({Key? key, required this.title, required this.choosedSetting})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              title, // Name
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.black,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4, // Change this property to align your content
            child: Text(
              choosedSetting, // Name
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                color: Colors.black,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios, // The arrow icon in the right of the row
              size: 12,
              color: Colors.black),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F39A1.png

To align the "choosedSetting" text, change the flex value.

I should also notice an error in your comment:

You have:               // the arrow icon in the left of the row

How to write correctly: // the arrow icon in the **right** of the row

 And here's what the Expanded widget does: Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex expand to fill the available space along the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column). If multiple children are expanded, the available space is divided among them according to the flex factor.

Comment: I checked your code and its answering my question so I accepted it.
But it led me to another problem, I updated my question with that problem. Please check it out if you can and want to.

Answer (score 0):

try to put textAlign: TextAlign.center, in the middle text like this :

```
    Text(
        subTitle, // Name
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: size.width * .0365,
          color: const Color(0x9C9C9C9C),
          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I already tried it. (I wrote that in the question).

Comment: Okay i didn't see it sorry. Then try to put a container instead of text like this :  Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('ABC'),
          ),

Answer (score 0):

Everything works by default, I took your code and ran it without changes, I am attaching the code and a screenshot:

```
  Column(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "Name1", // Name
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "ILikeBananas", // Name
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                          Icons
                              .arrow_forward_ios, // the arrow icon in the left of the row
                          size: 12,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "Name2", // Name
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Test Title", // Name
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                          Icons
                              .arrow_forward_ios, // the arrow icon in the left of the row
                          size: 12,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "Name3", // Name
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "A Lot Of Numbers Test", // Name
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                          Icons
                              .arrow_forward_ios, // the arrow icon in the left of the row
                          size: 12,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DznZw.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I copied the code you tested and the reason that you get the correct output is because your titles (first widget in the row) are in the same length. try put titles in different length from each other and you will see that it's not working. Thank you and hope you recheck my code.

Comment: I rechecked your code and fixed everything, you can look in the new post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then you want to shift the text to the left or right, align it in some way. To do this, simply change the value of the "flex" attribute on the Expanded widget.